# Service Tomcat7 Restart vs Stop and Start

Tags: tomcat, service

Is there any difference to doing:

```
service tomcat7 restart
```

vs

```
service tomcat7 stop
service tomcat7 start
```

Thanks

Comment: Downvote alert: This question falls below the bar for the minimum effort Serverfault expects [professionals](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity) to demonstrate. If you don't want to open the initscript and look, we probably don't either. Make the attempt first, then seek our help if you have trouble understanding something.

Comment: No there is no difference, simply look at the script and check the restart and start and stop block .. restart uses stop and start function defined earlier. Hope that helps you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No difference This is what I have in my tomcat init :

```
  restart)
        $0 stop
        sleep 1
        $0 start
        ;;
```

It calls stop first then wait for a second and calls start . You may increase sleep value if it takes time for you.